# How to get the touch point correctly in IOS8

Tags: rotation, ios8

In IOS 8, I set the device's default orientation is portrait, but sometimes, I want to change some views and keyboard to landscape, so I call the API setStatusBarOrientation. 
  In IOS 7, everything is ok, but In IOS 8, I can not get the touch points correctly.

[image]

As above picture shows, when I rotate the A view to B, if I touch B's shadow part, I can not get the correct coordination,it always return x = 640.

I get the x value as follow: x = [touch locationInView: [touch view]].x